# Multithreading Can't Find JAXB-API on AWS ECS Docker Container Only

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, multithreading, docker, jaxb

I am using JAXB for transforming and marshaling XML in a library which I have created that is used in a Spring Boot application. The application runs on AWS in a Docker container with ECS and currently uses CompletableFuture with the default thread pool to run through the library. The code is something like this:

```
CompletableFuture<Result> result = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> apiClient.callApiToGetXmlToTransform(someParameters))
                                                              .thenApplyAsync(searchResultStream -> transformResult(searchResultStream));
```

transformResult then has some mapping logic for transforming the incoming XML to the output format I need (Result). Everything works perfectly fine locally and no errors are thrown. However when the same code is run on AWS ECS in a Docker container the first thread transforms and returns correctly, but all additional threads throw this JAXB error:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
at
```

I have all the necessary JAXB dependencies on my build.gradle in both the library and the application. Why is this error being thrown just on the multiple threads on AWS and not locally?